# For real numbers $a,b,c$ calculate the value of: $\frac{c}{a+b}+\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}$ if we have...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For real numbers $a,b,c$ we have: $a+b+c=11$ and  $\frac1{a+b}+\frac1{b+c}+\frac1{c+a}=\frac{13}{17}$, calculate the value of: $\frac{c}{a+b}+\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}$
I think we should use a trick to solve this,because doing algebraic operations on this problem are too tedius!

Comment: Hint: multiply the two expressions that you've been given the value of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}=\frac{a+b+c}{b+c}+\frac{a+b+c}{a+c}+\frac{a+b+c}{a+b}-3=$$
$$=(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c} \right)-3=$$
$$=11\cdot\frac{13}{17}-3=\frac{92}{17}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{c}{a+b} +\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}=\frac{11-a-b}{a+b}+\frac{11-b-c}{b+c}+\frac{11-a-c}{c+a}
=(11\cdot \frac{13}{17})-3=\frac{92}{17}$

Comment: try here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you all very much! I am a freshman and I will improve myself here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

As $(a+b+c) ( \frac1{a+b}+\frac1{b+c}+\frac1{c+a})= 3+\frac{a}{b+c} +\frac{b}{c+a} + \frac{c}{a+b}$

---

Now applying the values given in question we get $\frac{a}{b+c} +\frac{b}{c+a} + \frac{c}{a+b}=(11 \cdot \frac{13}{17})- 3=\frac{92}{17}$